# What kind of objects are account and contact?

Tags: account, contact

If you look at [the ERD's of Sales & Service cloud](https://architect.salesforce.com/design/#architecture-gallery) then Account & Contact are shown in black and white. They do not belong to Sales Cloud or to Service Cloud. But to what "package" do they belong? Opportunity is a "Sales Cloud Object", Case is a "Service Cloud Object" but what kind of object is an account and a contact?

Under Related Entities on [this page](https://architect.salesforce.com/design/diagram-templates/data-model-notation). They say they are "available with a platform license" as far as I know there is no such thing as a platform license.

Answer (score 0):

- Sales Cloud users rely on Accounts and Contacts (counterparty of the Opportunity, people at the counterparty)
- Service Cloud users rely on Accounts and Contacts (customer's business entity that submitted a ticket; person at customer's business who submitted the ticket, including Experience Cloud user who is associated with a Contact)

As for [Platform License](https://www.salesforce.com/editions-pricing/platform/) - these are Platform Starter and Platform Plus licenses

From a development/configuration point of view, Account and Contact are like any other object (though see Person Accounts which conflate the two)

Comment: I was clearly wrong about the platform license. Would you say then that "Account & Contacts" are platform objects? In other words in the future the first referenced site in my question might also have an ERD of the datamodel of platform objects?

Comment: As follow up remark: Could you say then that Sales Cloud also gives you access to "Platform objects" and thus includes a platform license?

Comment: You are overthinking this. Account and Contact are standard objects that are available in many Salesforce licenses, including Platform licenses

Comment: so they don't belong to one license. I'm asking because I'm documenting the objects per "cloud", sales cloud, service cloud, ... But I don't know in which cloud to put them.

Comment: Accounts and Contacts (and others) are part of Sales Cloud _and_ Service Cloud.